# xarray assigning individual values to one variable/dataArray ends up assigning to all variables/dataArray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a script where I create a big xarray dataset full of np.nan and then assign individual values in a loop, with .loc (I also tried with positional indexing) ([doc](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing))

I get something quite weird.

Here is my minimal reproducible example :

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

levels = np.arange(0,3)
simNames = ['9airports_filter0dot7_v22']
airportList = ['Windhoek', 'Atlanta', 'Taipei']

emptyDA = xr.DataArray(np.nan, coords = [simNames, airportList, np.arange(0, 20428), levels], 
                       dims = ['simName', 'airport', 'profnum', 'level'])

ds = xr.Dataset({
    'iasi': emptyDA,
    'IM':   emptyDA,
    'IMS': emptyDA,
    'err': emptyDA,
    'sigma': emptyDA,
    'temp': emptyDA, 
    'dfs': emptyDA, 
    'ocf': emptyDA, 
    'rcf': emptyDA, 
    'time': emptyDA, 
    'surfPres': emptyDA })

ds = ds.assign_coords(time = ds.time) # pass time from variable to coord

ds['dfs'].loc['9airports_filter0dot7_v22', 'Windhoek', 0, 0] = 3
```

I get my scalar "3" assigned to all dataArrays:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (simName: 1, airport: 3, profnum: 20428, level: 3)
Coordinates:
  * simName   (simName) <U25 '9airports_filter0dot7_v22'
  * airport   (airport) <U8 'Windhoek' 'Atlanta' 'Taipei'
  * profnum   (profnum) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 20423 20424 20425 20426 20427
  * level     (level) int64 0 1 2
Data variables:
    iasi      (simName, airport, profnum, level) float64 3.0 nan nan ... nan nan
    IM        (simName, airport, profnum, level) float64 3.0 nan nan ... nan nan
    IMS       (simName, airport, profnum, level) float64 3.0 nan nan ... nan nan
    err       (simName, airport, profnum, level) float64 3.0 nan nan ... nan nan
    sigma     (simName, airport, profnum, level) float64 3.0 nan nan ... nan nan
    temp      (simName, airport, profnum, level) float64 3.0 nan nan ... nan nan
    dfs       (simName, airport, profnum, level) float64 3.0 nan nan ... nan nan
    ocf       (simName, airport, profnum, level) float64 3.0 nan nan ... nan nan
    rcf       (simName, airport, profnum, level) float64 3.0 nan nan ... nan nan
    time      (simName, airport, profnum, level) float64 3.0 nan nan ... nan nan
    surfPres  (simName, airport, profnum, level) float64 3.0 nan nan ... nan nan
```

although this simpler code works correctly :

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

ds = xr.Dataset({'var1': (('x', 'y'), [[np.nan, np.nan],[np.nan, np.nan]]), 'var2': (('x', 'y'), [[np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan]])})

ds['var1'].loc[0, 0] = 1
```

Comment: creating xarray DataArrays starting from numpy arrays is a perfectly fine way to do it. so is going from pandas to xarray. You can assign to a DataArray with `da.loc[...] = ...`. If you have a specific question, go ahead and try to implement it in xarray and show us what you've tried and what's not working, and we can help you move forward :)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I edited my question to add something strange that I did not see yesterday

Comment: Hi there - and I forgot to welcome you to stack overflow! Please see the guide to [ask] - specifically, avoid asking multiple questions in one. I don't see the same behavior when trying a very similar workflow. Can you check out the docs on creating a [mre] and see if you can create a full workflow (start to finish) which reproduces the issue you're seeing? As it is I think this question is likely to be closed as it's asking multiple questions at once and it's describing a behavior that's not reproducible (at least not for me). Thanks!

Comment: to get you started, here's a toy dataset: `ds = xr.Dataset({'var1': (('x', ), [np.nan, np.nan]), 'var2': (('x', ), [np.nan, np.nan])})`. `ds['var1'].loc[{'x': 0}] = 1` only modifies `var1` :)

Comment: thanks. I added the reproducible example in the question.

Comment: Ohhhh- - the issue is because all of your data arrays are actually the same object. When constructing the dataset use `emptyDA.copy()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is occurring because when you initialize an [`xarray.Dataset`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.html) with a dictionary of DataArrays, it makes a shallow copy of the DataArrays, allowing each to have different metadata but not duplicating the underlying numpy arrays.

You can see this behavior with a small example based on your question.

First I'll create a new numpy array with all NaNs:

```py
In [1]: import xarray as xr, numpy as np, pandas as pd

In [2]: np_arr = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])

In [3]: np_arr
Out[3]: array([nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

We can see the actual memory address ID here:

```py
In [4]: hex(id(np_arr))
Out[4]: '0x1186570f0'
```

Remember this address - we'll come back to it: `'0x1186570f0'`

Next we'll create a DataArray wrapping this numpy array:

```py
In [5]: da = xr.DataArray(np_arr, dims=['x'], coords=[range(4)])

In [6]: da
Out[6]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 4)>
array([nan, nan, nan, nan])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2 3
```

The DataArray itself gets a new ID, but the underlying array is just pointing to the same numpy object at `'0x1186570f0'`:

```py
In [7]: hex(id(da))
Out[7]: '0x118668460'

In [8]: hex(id(da.data))
Out[8]: '0x1186570f0'
```

When you initialize a Dataset with a dictionary of DataArrays, xarray makes a shallow copy of the arrays. Note that the reference to the DataArray address has changed:

```py
In [9]: ds = xr.Dataset({'var1': da, 'var2': da})

In [10]: hex(id(ds['var1']))
Out[10]: '0x1186d5340'

In [11]: hex(id(ds['var2']))
Out[11]: '0x1186e0fa0'
```

This allows each array to have different attributes/metadata

```py
In [12]: ds['var1'].name
Out[12]: 'var1'

In [13]: ds['var2'].name
Out[13]: 'var2'
```

However, the data is *still* pointing to the original numpy address:

```py
In [14]: hex(id(ds['var1'].data))
Out[14]: '0x1186570f0'

In [15]: hex(id(ds['var2'].data))
Out[15]: '0x1186570f0'
```

This is a good thing, because it means working with xarray will not blow up your memory usage unless you tell it do. But you do have to tell it to copy the data if you would like it to.

You can do this with a deep copy, which [`xarray.DataArray.copy`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.copy.html) does by default:

```py
In [16]: ds = xr.Dataset({'var1': da.copy(), 'var2': da.copy()})

In [17]: hex(id(ds['var1'].data))
Out[17]: '0x1186b23f0'

In [18]: hex(id(ds['var2'].data))
Out[18]: '0x118660090'
```

Answer (score 1):

okey, I have understood my mistake: emptyDA is not copied for each new variable but point to the same object. Inserting emptyDA.copy() instead of emptyDA resolve the problem. I thought that the creation of the xarray object would have copied the data.
Thanks for your help